# Ansible define a custom service path and notify only if the service is restarted

Tags: ansible

I'm working on a new opsware agent service check on AIX, its agent path is /etc/rc.d/init.d/opsware-agent.

Firstly please let me know how to define this variable path and call in service.

Secondly  it should run the command only if this opsware agent service has been restarted. How to do it, since below one is not working.

```
- name: Ensure Opsware agent is running on AIX 
service: name={{ aix_service_path }} state=started enabled=yes
register: aix_status


 - name: Opsware AIX Notify only if it failed
 when: aix_status|success
 notify:
 - hardware refresh
 - software refresh

- name: hardware refresh
command: chdir=/opt/opsware/agent/pylibs/cog/ ./bs_hardware

- name: software refresh
command: chdir=/opt/opsware/agent/pylibs/cog/ ./bs_Software
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me assume the YML formatting is correct and just got broken in your post. Otherwise you first need to indent your lines correctly.

Then make sure your handlers are inside `handlers/main.yml`. In your post it looks like everything is in the same file which then would of course get executed on every play.

Finally you can trigger your handlers in the service task, no need to have the dummy task, which additionally wouldn't work because there actually is no action defined.

So this should work:

**your_role/tasks/main.yml:**

```
---

- name: Ensure Opsware agent is running on AIX 
  service: name={{ aix_service_path }} state=started enabled=yes
  notify:
  - hardware refresh
  - software refresh

...
```

**your_role/handlers/main.yml:**

```
---

- name: hardware refresh
  command: chdir=/opt/opsware/agent/pylibs/cog/ ./bs_hardware

- name: software refresh
  command: chdir=/opt/opsware/agent/pylibs/cog/ ./bs_Software

...
```

The handlers will be notified only when the service status is `changed`.

How you define `aix_service_path` depends on what you want to archive. You can define a default value in `your_role/defaults/main.yml`:

```
---

aix_service_path: foo

...
```

Or force it by defining it in `your_role/vars/main.yml` - same format as defaults above.

You can pass parameters in the role calls in your playbook, e.g.

```
  roles:
    - role: your_role
      aix_service_path: foo
```

A parameter passed like this would override a definition in `defaults/main.yml`, but not those defined in `vars/main.yml`.

You can define it in a `vars` section in the playbook.

You can pass it on command-line when calling your playbook.

```
ansible-playbook ... --extra-vars "aix_service_path=foo"
```

Or define it as server- or group var. As well you can define variables in the inventory... There really are a ton of options for defining variables. You have to decide which fits your needs. Check out the [variables section in the Ansible docs](http://docs.ansible.com/playbooks_variables.html) for more details.

Comment: thanks for that. Regarding "role: your_role" After defining a role in /vars/main.yml, where should i call this role? I mean should i call this role in /tasks/main.yml? If yes how to do this.

Comment: Roles will be referenced in your playbook. It is recommended to not have tasks but only roles in your playbook and all tasks in your roles. Have a look at http://docs.ansible.com/playbooks_roles.html#roles

Comment: And here you can see a basic directory structure including an example role: http://docs.ansible.com/playbooks_best_practices.html#directory-layout

Comment: @udondan Handlers can be in the same playbook file as long as they are under `handlers:` block. See http://docs.ansible.com/playbooks_intro.html#handlers-running-operations-on-change

Comment: Yes, but we don't like anything but roles in our playbooks, do we? :D

Comment: @udondan I have published it on git [link](https://github.com/praveen8735/ansible/tree/master/roles/opsware) can you let me know whether i have define it right.